# Lemon parser - how to handle result from lemon parser

Tags: c++, lemon

http://linuxgazette.net/106/chirico.html
In example 1 , The result is printed in example1.y but I want to handle that result in main.c . How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The result is printed because the input said `program ::= ... { std::cout << ... }`. I.e. the result of parsing is processed by the top-level rule.

You might want to use `%extra_argument { MyClass *pThis }`. Lemon will then add a 4th parameter to `Parse` which is available in action rules as `pThis`.